# С первого не обрабатывается действие у UIDatePicker.countDownTimer

Tags: ios, swift

Столкнулся с такой проблемой и ни на stackoverflow, ни в гугле не нашёл решения.

Я программно создаю UIDatePicker и задаю ему тип countDownTimer.
Так же вешаю ему действие на valueChanged. И проблема в том, что он воспроизводит это действие только со второго раза. Нашёл, что надо ему выставлять дату (setDate), но не помогло. Видел ещё извращения по типу размещения в viewDidLoad диспатчей, но это показалось странным.

Может кто-нибудь знает как это лечится, а то голову уже несколько часов ломаю и никак не могу найти решения :(

```
        var dateComp : DateComponents = DateComponents()
        dateComp.hour = 0
        dateComp.minute = 5
        let calendar : Calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        let date = calendar.date(from: dateComp)!

        let datePickerView:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.countDownTimer
        datePickerView.minuteInterval = 5

        datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ATLOneTaskVC.datePickerLogWorkValueChanged(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
        datePickerView.setDate(date, animated: true)

        textField.inputView = datePickerView
```

Про такое составление даты прочитал на каком-то из советов и попробовал, но тоже не помогло :(

Comment: какой то код можно посмотреть?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как оказалось, это существующий баг. Есть радары. Широкая общественность предлагает такой воркэраунд: обернуть setDate в диспатч

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {


        var textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 100))
        self.view.addSubview(textField)


        var dateComp : DateComponents = DateComponents()
        dateComp.hour = 0
        dateComp.minute = 5
        let calendar : Calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        let date = calendar.date(from: dateComp)!

        let datePickerView:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
        textField.inputView = datePickerView
        datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(process), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
        datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.countDownTimer
        datePickerView.minuteInterval = 5
        let deadlineTime = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(1)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadlineTime) {
            datePickerView.setDate(date, animated: true)
        }



    }

    func process() {
        print("process")
    }

}
```

Comment: Такой вариант пробовал, не помогает(

Comment: Просто удивляет, что стандартный пикер с таким багом. Может легче сделать свой пикер?

Comment: у меня так работает

Comment: @DEM909 добавил в ответ весь код, который я использовал для тестирования

Comment: возможно время надо увеличить, если у вас там много всего происходит

Comment: на работе попробую, спасибо большое! У меня он вызывается в textfield, который находится в UIAlertController, возможно из-за этого проблема. Но спасибо большое за наводку, буду разбираться!

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо выставлять дату пикеру после его показа. Например, в случае с inputView для UITextField подпишитесь делегатом и обновляйте дату в методе

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
```

Если же реализуете свой UIResponder, то обновляйте после вызова becomeFirstResponder()

Выставление даты в другой итерации RunLoop хак, фу :)